# Azure App Service - C++ 2010 redistributable package support

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, visual-c++-runtime

I'm trying to investigate support for our ASP.net application when deployed to **Azure App Services**.

I've published the application to Azure App Services and seem to be hitting an issue with the dependency on the **C++ 2010 redistributable package**.

The error I receive is "Could not load file or assembly 'mfcm100.dll' or one of its dependencies. A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed".

I'm fairly certain that Azure App Services is not the correct solution for web applications that have third party dependencies and that other solutions such as *Cloud Services (web roles), Virtual Machines or Service Fabric* are more suitable however I'd like to be 100% sure that there is absolutely no way we can build, package or publish an ASP.net application to with a dependency on something like *Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable* to Azure App Services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried copying the needed DLL into your Web App files?

Comment: Yes I've tried copying them into the bin folder of the Web App, which resulted in the "Could not load file or assembly 'mfcm100.dll' or one of its dependencies. A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed" message as above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a technique which I think may work:

- Drop that binary in some folder in your app, e.g. `d:\home\FolderOnPath`
- Use the technique described [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables) to add that folder to the path.
- Restart your app

In theory that DLL should now be on the path and loadable from your app.